# How can I store a user's roles before muting to return after the mute expires

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make it so that once I mute the user, their roles are removed and stored so that once they get unmuted, they get their roles back

```js
let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "muted")
        if (!muterole) {
            try {
                muterole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                    data: {
                        name: "muted",
                        color: "#514f48",
                        permissions: []
                    }
                })
                message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel) => {
                    await channel.createOverwrite(muterole, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                        ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                        SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
                        ATTACH_FILES: false,
                        SPEAK: false,
                        CONNECT: false,
                    })
                })
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        mutee.roles.set([])
        mutee.roles.add(muterole.id).then(() => {
            mutee.send(`Hello, you have been muted in ${message.guild.name} for ${reason || "No Reason"}`).catch(err => console.log(err))
            const sembed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("GREEN")
                .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
                .setDescription(`${mutee.user.username} was successfully muted.`)
            message.channel.send(sembed);
        })
```

Comment: You'd have to store the roles in a JSON file or preferably a database since JSON files could break easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using a database - quick.db

Answer (score 1):

Just create an objet with he's ID on key and he's roles in an array that contains every IDs of he's roles, then save this into a JSON file with the `fs` library, it's simple to use and you don't have to install it, it's integrated in node.